# The graph of the 3-degree polynomial.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$f(x) =x^3+ ax^2+ bx +c, (c> 0)$

There is a $f(x)$'s the tangent point $P$ which lie on the $x $axis.

And the graph of the $f(x)$ is symmetric for the point $Q $on $y$ axis.

Also there is a intersection point$ R $between $f$ and $x $axis.

Say the Area of the $triangle PQR$ is $6$. Then what is $a+b+c$?

---

This is definetly sure that all we find just $f(1)$.

But the answer said $-1$

When we consider the graph of the $f $since the $c$ is a positive it look like the answer is incorrect.
[image]

What do you think? How could I solve that? Thanks. :)

Comment: You could start by concluding that $a=0$, because of the symmetry of the $f$ graph for the point $Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $f'(-\alpha )=0$ so $$2\alpha+\beta =0\implies \beta = -2\alpha$$

Since $f(0)= -\alpha ^2\beta $ you have $${-\alpha ^2\beta \cdot 3\alpha \over 2} = 6$$

So $\alpha ^2 = \sqrt{2}$ and thus \begin{eqnarray}a+b+c&=&f(1)-1\\ &=& (1-\alpha)^2(1+2\alpha)-1\\&=&...\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks for your hint :) the answer was incorrect